# Can't hit index.jsp in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a Spring 2.5.6 MVC application that I'm running on Tomcat 7.  However, when I try to access the index.jsp page under `http://localhost:8080/myapp-web/`, I'm getting a 404 error.  The context-root is /myapp-web/.

The servlet.xml:

```
...
<bean name="/app.htm" class="com.myapp.web.MyAppController">
        ...
  </bean>
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
  </bean>
```

The jsp file under WEB-INF is: index.jsp and is listed in the web.xml as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Everything appears to be correct here, but since I'm getting the 404, I realize I'm not finding the resource.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**Aftermath:**

There may be another issue with the original code, but I was able to get another tutorial working and I understand the mappings better from the answers I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either change `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />` to `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />` or move index.jsp to `/WEB-INF/jsp/`...

**EDIT:**

Try change `servlet-mapping` to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I missed that, but it's still not hitting the jsp after it got moved over.

Comment: Also, do you have `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` registered in your web.xml?

Comment: I think that request for index doesn't match pattern `*.htm` defined in `servlet-mapping` and thus doesn't even hit Spring MVC. See edited answer.

Comment: Good suggestions, but after trying them, I'm still not hitting the page for some reason.

Comment: Again, is http://localhost:8080/myapp-web/index not accessible or is just localhost:8080/myapp-web not redirecting properly?

Comment: Nothing outside of http://localhost:8080/ is accessible.  I just tried it with another Spring MVC app created using STS to generate a template application, but I got the same results.  Looks like some issue related to the Tomcat 7 configuration.

Comment: Can you change `<url-pattern>` value to `/*` and check again (sorry for typo). Also, it'll be easier if you enable debugging: add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to log4j.properties.